# Docker container on Red Hat Linux server 5.9

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, docker, lxc

Can I install Docker on Red Hat server 5.9 so I can take an image container from an installed software and move it to another server?

Or should it be enough to update the Kernel up to version 3 so Docker can run?

Comment: Why are you trying to get such an old distro to work? That's not even the latest version of RHEL5 and RHEL5 as a whole will be EOL'd next March.

Comment: @Bratchley i want to stop using the RHEL 5 and move to RHEL 7. But because I can't touch the software in the old RHEL, then i should go for VM or Docker and i prefer Docker as it's lightweight. Also I can't reinstall the software as I don't have the installation media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docker's website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/rhel/) states that it can be installed on any 64 bit distribution of RHEL.

However, the kernel must be 3.10 at a minimum.

Check your kernel version first with the following command: `uname -r`.

Comment: The Kernel i have is 2.6, do you think if I updated it, I could harm some existing software?

Comment: Id take a look at RHEL's documentation and take the precautionary steps before upgrading your kernel: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-kernel-preparing.html

Comment: Furthermore, keep a back up of your original kernel so if something goes wrong you can reinstall back to the original kernel

Comment: u think it's wiser to have an iso of the whole server and try somewhere else or ur kernel backup idea is enough?

Comment: To be honest, I never did a kernel upgrade on that version of RHEL but why don't you look up the steps of upgrading your kernel on RHEL 5.x

Comment: If it means anything, what I usually do when using Docker is create a VM and dedicate the VM to Docker...

Comment: u mean u do that so that u won't affect the system right?

Comment: No. I just prefer to dedicate a server/VM to creating Docker scripts and running containers.